# Why my Spring Boot Can not find redis cache name...?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

First of all, sorry for my poor english...

I have some problems with my spring boot application.

I want to apply redis cache in my specific method. So I created CacheConfig and coded RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer

This is my Redis CacheConfig file

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class CacheConfig {

    /**
     * GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer
     * list 역직렬화시 에러 발생할 수도..?
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeKeysWith(
                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())
                )
                .serializeValuesWith(
                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer())
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
        System.out.println("CacheType.PERFORMANCE_LIST.cacheName = " + CacheType.PERFORMANCE_LIST.cacheName);
        System.out.println("CacheType.DETAIL.cacheName = " + CacheType.PERFORMANCE_DETAIL.cacheName);
        return (builder) -> builder
                .withCacheConfiguration(CacheType.PERFORMANCE_LIST.cacheName,
                        RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                                .prefixCacheNameWith("cache")
                                .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(CacheType.PERFORMANCE_LIST.getExpireTime()))
                                .disableCachingNullValues()
                                .serializeKeysWith(
                                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())
                                )
                                .serializeValuesWith(
                                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer())
                                ))
                .withCacheConfiguration(CacheType.PERFORMANCE_DETAIL.cacheName,
                        RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                                .prefixCacheNameWith("cache")
                                .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(CacheType.PERFORMANCE_DETAIL.getExpireTime()))
                                .disableCachingNullValues()
                                .serializeKeysWith(
                                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())
                                )
                                .serializeValuesWith(
                                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer())
                                ));
    }

    @Getter
    private enum CacheType{
        PERFORMANCE_LIST("performanceList", 12),
        PERFORMANCE_DETAIL("performanceDetail", 12);

        private String cacheName;
        private Integer expireTime;

        CacheType(String cacheName, Integer expireTime) {
            this.cacheName = cacheName;
            this.expireTime = expireTime;
        }

        private static final Map<String, CacheType> CACHE_TYPE_MAP;

        static{
            Map<String, CacheType> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            for (CacheType cacheType : CacheType.values()) {
                map.put(cacheType.name(), cacheType);
            }
            CACHE_TYPE_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
        }

        public static CacheType get(String name){
            if (!StringUtils.hasText(name)){
                throw new CustomException(ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST.getMessage(), ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            return Optional.ofNullable(CACHE_TYPE_MAP.get(name)).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException(ErrorCode.CACHE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND.getMessage(), ErrorCode.CACHE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND));
        }
    }
}
```

And This is my specific method that i want to use caching

```
@Cacheable(value = "performanceList", key = "{#sort, #pageable.pageNumber, #pageable.pageSize}")
    public List<CommonPerformanceDto> getPerformanceBySortAndPage(Pageable pageable, String sort) {
        return performanceRepositoryPort.findAllBySortAndPaging(pageable, sort).stream().map(CommonPerformanceDto::domainToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

And My ProjectApplication Setting is

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Profile("dev")
    @Bean
    public TestDataInit testDataInit(ArtistRepository artistRepository, PerformanceRepository performanceRepository, UserRepository userRepository, FollowRepository followRepository,
                                     ReviewRepository reviewRepository, UserImageRepository userImageRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserSearchRepository userSearchRepository,
                                     ZzimRepositoryPort zzimRepositoryPort, PerformerRepository performerRepository) {
        return new TestDataInit(artistRepository, performanceRepository, userRepository,
                followRepository, reviewRepository, userImageRepository, passwordEncoder,
                userSearchRepository, zzimRepositoryPort, performerRepository);
    }

}
```

But When i requested some api end-point that i applied @Cacheable Method, then I got error like

```
Cannot find cache named 'performanceList' for Builder[public] caches=[performanceList] | key='{#sort, #pageable.pageNumber, #pageable.pageSize}' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false']
```

Why this error happened?? Please help me...